# iOS app runs for only 1 second in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have 2 classes, `ViewController` class, and `Worker`. All the code that I need to run in the background is in the `Worker` class.

**My `ViewController` looks something like this:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 //create an instance of 'Worker'
}
- buttonClick {
 //call the 'manager' method in the worker instance that was just created (do this method as a background thread)
}
```

**My `Worker` class looks something like this:**

```
- (void)manager {
    //call 'repeat' method as a background thread    
}

- (void)repeat {
    //call 'innerWorker' method as a background thread    
}
- (void)innerWorker {
    //do work
}
```

**The `repeat` method needs to get run every second.**

I've tried the 2 following ways to make the `repeat` method run every second.

**Method 1 :**

```
timerObj = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**Method 2:** 
Putting this code at the end of `repeat`:

```
dispatch_queue_t q_background = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, q_background, ^(void){
    [self repeatMethod];
});
```

Both of these 2 methods work fine as long as the app is in the foreground but the moment I press the home button, the `repeat` method runs one last time, but does not call the `innerWorker` method and then the app is suspended. I know this by using NSLogs all over the place.

I realize Method 2 is a bit of a hack but that's fine as this is an internal app that I wont be publishing.

All the methods are called as background threads using this code: eg:

```
dispatch_queue_t q_background = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
        dispatch_async(q_background, ^{
            [self repeatMethod];
        });
```

I'm new to iOS so maybe I'm missing something small here. I just want my app to keep running in the background. Please help me.

Comment: Please read into the background app development guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Comment: @Krumelur thanks but I already did. My app is fairly small so I'm hoping theres a simpler fix or hoping to find out if there is somewhere else im screwing up because I'm still new to this.

Comment: No, there is not. All threads are suspended unless you use one of the background mode.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: the dispatch_queue priority has nothing to do with running in background ... it is the priority in the queue.

Here are the info:

> DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH Items dispatched to the queue will run at high priority, i.e. the queue will be scheduled for execution before any default priority or low priority queue.
>
> DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT Items dispatched to the queue will run at the default priority, i.e. the queue will be scheduled for execution after all high priority queues have been scheduled, but before any low priority queues have been scheduled.
>
> DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW Items dispatched to the queue will run at low priority, i.e. the queue will be scheduled for execution after all default priority and high priority queues have been scheduled.
>
> DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND Items dispatched to the queue will run at background priority, i.e. the queue will be scheduled for execution after all higher priority queues have been scheduled and the system will run items on this queue on a thread with background status as per setpriority(2) (i.e. disk I/O is throttled and the thread's scheduling priority is set to lowest value).

For "real" background operations check this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

The answer to your question depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Well,  the complete objective is to run `repeat` method in the background forever but right now, I'm trying to atleast get it to run for 10 mins. I'm so confused by how that method runs one last time after the app is sent to the background (I put an NSLog `in applicationDidEnterBackground`), but nothing thereafter.

Comment: you can not simply keep any app alive in background, as Brian pointed out there only some usecases where continous running in background is aloud. You should check the linked apple documentation what suits your need.

Comment: I realize that, but my understanding is that every app, regardless of what's mentioned in the info.plist is given a few minutes in the background. I have mentioned I need location access in my info.plist but that's beside the point. Please correct me if my assumption is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong .. you must explicitly start a background action ... not a normal GDC queue call with background priority. This first part of the apple documentation.

Comment: Can you answer a question for me please? In the link you posted, `Listing 3-1 ` says `  bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWith...` , do you mind telling me what type of object bgTask is?

Comment: Sure: Type is -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier =
A unique token that identifies a request to run in the background.

Declaration
OBJECTIVE-C
typedef NSUInteger UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier;

Comment: @donga Even if it is hard to believe: there is no way around Finite Length tasks in your case. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

Only the following types of apps, with the appropriate plist flag set, can execute a background process while the app is still in the foreground:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
  such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in    the background
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all    times, such
  as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet    Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content    regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

If your app falls outside of one of those categories, and will go through app store approval, you will need to devise another strategy for doing the background work you desire to preform.

More info can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read that paragraph many times. But I realize that apps are always allowed to run for a few minutes in the background before they're suspended. Mine is given only 1 second.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen varying times my app has been allowed to finish background tasks. I saw variations between iOS versions, and based on system 'load' (number of apps running or really in their background states). I was able to see things run longer if I killed everything on the system. However, that is not a real maintainable model for deploying an app :)

Comment: I see. For testing purposes, my iPhone is pretty much empty with no other apps running in the background but the 1 second seems to be all im getting (always).